# MissingResourceException : Can't find bundle for base name (GCM webservice in android)

Tags: android

Trying to implement localization support in GCM service. I tried creating the resource bundle with and without locale in src folder as well as in webapp/web-inf , but I ended with below exception. Please guide in resolving this issue.

[My Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxRTT.jpg)

[Code to get bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK9sy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this issue by moving the resource bundle inside classes folder.( inside web-inf)